# Postgresql date range query with year and week number

Tags: postgresql

Hi I would like to store the number of working hours for a given week in a table with, 
    hours, year, week

so I can aggregate the hours for a week quickly, where week is the ISO week number.

I then want to do a date range filter query on this table, let's say

From 2018-12-24 to 2019-01-21 (year 2018 week 52 to 2019 week 4).

If the user pass the year and week, then I would need to do a range check on a compound index where you compare the year value first, and then the week number.

How should I structure the query and index to efficiently retrieve records with this range?

This is a basic attempt, given a start year and start week, and an end year and end week:

```
select year, week, hours
  from
  weekly hours
  where((year = 2018 and week >= 52) OR year > 2018) AND
       ((year = 2019 and week <=3) OR year < 2019)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare more than one column with the `<=` or `>=` operator:

```
select *
from weekly_hours
where (year, week) >= (2018,52)
  and (year, week) <= (2019,3);
```

That query can make use of an index on both columns, e.g.

```
create index on weekly_hours (year, week);
```

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name, this is what I was looking for, and I tested it out with some sample data and comparing both columns works.  I have a related question whether this is the best way to represent this data: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56468652/weekly-hour-allocation-problem-in-rails-and-postgresql, if you have any suggestion, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the week as an absolute number and use this for your range queries. An expression index can be used for the absolute week calculation.

```
create table weekly_hours (
  year int,
  week int,
  hours int
);

insert into weekly_hours 
  (year, week, hours) 
  values 
  (2018, 52, 10), 
  (2019, 4, 9),
  (2019, 10, 9);

-- expression index that generates the absolute week
create index weekly_hours_absweek_idx on weekly_hours((year * 53 + week));

-- range query 
select year, week, hours 
from weekly_hours 
where
    year * 53 + week >= 2018 * 53 + 52
    and year * 53 + week <= 2019 * 53 + 4;
```

Comment: That's no issue. It's only important to multiply by a number that is greater or equal to the maximum weeks. You could also use for example 100 as a multiplier. Then you would calculate absolute week values like 201852 and 201904. The gaps won't affect the range query.

Comment: Thanks @FlorianGutmann", I had a look at your answer and the one from @a_horse_with_no_name.  I think your solution would work as well, but I probably would prefer the other.

Comment: Agreed, I'd prefer his too 